# How to declare a non-activity class in the manifest file of an Android library?

Tags: android, android-library

in order to refactor my code, I'm moving some methods I'm using in every project to an Android library.

Eg. I've created a simple library project with the following class:

```
public class HttpUtils {

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
          context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
}
```

and the following (default) manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.utils"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can import it in another Android project using

```
import com.xxx.utils.http.HttpUtils;
```

but if I try using `HttpUtils.isNetworkAvailable`, I get `HttpUtils.isNetworkAvailable cannot be resolved to a type`.

I read that, for a library activity, it should be added to the manifest file, but how can I add a simple class, like my `HttpUtils`, in the library manifest to be able to access its method from another project?

Comment: Why would your declare it in the manifest ? Just make your main project reference your "reusable" one, and add to build path if needed.

Comment: Android library generally don't need manifest.xml at all; since the manifest defines an *application*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you like to add this class like a library. Add it just in your package, then you can call it from any Activity like that :

```
boolean isNetworkAvailable = new HttpUtils().isNetworkAvailable(this);
```

Or make isNetworkAvailable static :

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {....}
```

Then you could call it simply:

```
boolean isNetworkAvailable = HttpUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this);
```

In this way, there is nothing to declare in the manifest file.

EDIT :
ok, I understand. You have several projects. So for this, you have 2 choices :

1)you can create from eclipse new project and in the second window select "Mark this project as a library". Then in all your project add this library project in the build path

2)create a jar file

Answer (score 1):

> how can I add a simple class in the library manifest

You don't.

You have some other problem, such as:

- not having the library project correctly attached to the host project
- having the wrong import (e.g., to some other class named `HttpUtils`)

It would help if you had the correct error message. AFAIK, it is not possible for "cannot be resolved to a type" to be put on the name of a method.